# Combined multiple within-group effect sizes

Tags: meta-analysis, aggregation

I'm conducting a meta-analysis on observational studies examined the association of age with different drug groups prescription and in order to combine the effect sizes of all drug groups together, a three-level meta-analysis was conducted using log odds ratio and its variance. However, I have experienced an issue with few studies reporting age in more than 2 categories resulting in reporting more than one effect size per drug group per study.

EX: study-id, Drug group , Age category , OR, 95%C.I:

```
study 1, group1, 45-65 vs. < 45, 0.70[0.68-0.72]

study 1 , group1, >=65 vs. < 45, 0.41[0.32-0.42]

study 1 , group2, 45-65 vs. < 45, 1.87[1.83-1.91]

study 1 , group2, >=65 vs. < 45, 2.65[2.59-2.7]
```

Therefore, to avoid applying four-level meta-analysis since this issue was found in only 4 of included studies. How within-group effect sizes can be combined (; combine 0.70[0.68-0.72] and 0.41[0.32-0.42] into one OR and 95% C.I)?
Note: the sample size of each category was not reported in the study, so the agg function in R could not be applied to combine within-group effect sizes. Also, baseline data was not reported to be used in re-constructing age categories and calculating crud OR per group for that study. What is the best way to combine within-group effect sizes considering that data about the sample size of each category is missing?

Many thanks

Comment: Given the lack of information available to you I suspect contacting study authors is your only way forward.